# How to get the union of two lists using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Consider the following lists:

```
a = ['Orange and Banana', 'Orange Banana']
b = ['Grapes', 'Orange Banana']
```

How to get the following result:

```
c = ['Orange and Banana', 'Orange Banana', 'Grapes']
```

Comment: Who voted to close as off-topic?

Comment: @recursive I did not, but it sure is offtopic.

Comment: my question is specifically about list comprehension. that post doesn't deal the question with list comprehension. there is an answer, but it is wrong

Comment: [ x for x in b if x in a ] this doesn't work

Comment: If you're asking "How do I do this with a list comprehension, whether or not a list comprehension is a reasonable way to do this", that's a paradigm [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). And if you're _not_ asking that, it's a dup.

Comment: Voting to re-open because the OP *explicitly* is asking how to do this with list comprehension: 1) title/tag 2) "my question is specifically about list comprehension. that post doesn't deal the question with list comprehension. there is an answer, but it is wrong"

Comment: @user2864740: In that case, the answer is "don't do this with a list comprehension, do it the way that answer says".

Comment: @abarnert Which is a poor answer - but a good addendum/note.

Comment: @user2864740: That list comprehension will give you the intersection, not the union.

Comment: @user2864740: A question for which the only good answer is a poor answer is a question that should be closed.

Comment: "My Y is right" is too prevalent on SO. The OP *knows* about Y but is *explicitly asking about X*.

Comment: it give this: ['Orange Banana']

Comment: @Coddy I think it's a fair question, but could be asked differently - too much XY juice in this post. Start with the non-working list-comprehension, explain what it does (as abarnert pointed out it's the intersection), and what is desired. At least then it might get some consideration ..

Comment: You can do `a + [x for x in b if x not in a]`, but this is incredibly stupid. Or you could just do `[x for x in <correct answer>]`, or something even dumber. But there is nothing in listcomp syntax that maps to unioning things together in any reasonable way, so there is no non-stupid answer to this question.

Answer (score 91):

If you have more than 2 list, you should use:

```
>>> a = ['Orange and Banana', 'Orange Banana']
>>> b = ['Grapes', 'Orange Banana']
>>> c = ['Foobanana', 'Orange and Banana']
>>> list(set().union(a,b,c))
['Orange and Banana', 'Foobanana', 'Orange Banana', 'Grapes']
```

Comment: Why put `a, b, c` into a list just so you can explode that list again? Just do `set().union(a, b, c)`.

Comment: @abarnert, BTW, great point on `next(takewhile(not_, count()))` =)

Comment: By using `set()`, you're eliminating duplicates from the lists. Notice `'Orange Banana'` appears twice in the input, but only once in the output. Sometimes this may be desirable, sometimes not. It's an important characteristic to note, and we really need to know how to do both ways.

Comment: ```set(a + b + c)``` Should be faster as it requires less operations

Answer (score 21):

```
>>> list(set(a).union(b))
['Orange and Banana', 'Orange Banana', 'Grapes']
```

Thanks @abarnert