# Concatenate files with different and overlapping columns

Tags: python, csv, concatenation

I have three csv files.

One with tittles:

```
names1=['Date','Conc','Flow','SZ','SB','RZ','RB','Fraction','Attenuation','Conc_less_-200_flag','Conc_greater_500_flag','Wind Speed','Wind Direction','Wind_direction_Flag','Wind_Speed_Less_than_4','Middle','Wind_Speed_Greater_than_10','Multiple conditions']
```

First rows:

```
Date,Conc,Flow,SZ,SB,RZ,RB,Fraction,Attenuation,Conc_less_-200_flag,Conc_greater_500_flag,Wind Speed,Wind Direction,Wind_direction_Flag,Wind_Speed_Less_than_4,Middle,Wind_Speed_Greater_than_10,Multiple conditions
2004-02-27 00:00:00,,,,,,,,,,,6.524999999999999,177.75,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0
2004-02-27 01:00:00,,,,,,,,,,,6.991666666666667,197.83333333333334,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0
```

The other two:

```
names2=['Date','Chanel0','Chanel1','Chanel2','Chanel3','Chanel4','Chanel5','Chanel6','Chanel7','Conc_less_-200_flag','Conc_greater_500_flag','Wind Speed','Wind Direction','Wind_direction_Flag','Wind_Speed_Less_than_4','Middle','Wind_Speed_Greater_than_10','Multiple conditions']
```

First rows:

```
Date,Chanel0,Chanel1,Chanel2,Chanel3,Chanel4,Chanel5,Chanel6,Chanel7,Conc_less_-200_flag,Conc_greater_500_flag,Wind Speed,Wind Direction,Wind_direction_Flag,Wind_Speed_Less_than_4,Middle,Wind_Speed_Greater_than_10,Multiple conditions
2012-01-23 08:00:00,-2402.3575757575754,-2418.8121212121237,-2423.983863636366,-2422.913745454546,-2423.983863636366,-2422.814151515151,-2423.242424242424,-2422.4842121212123,1.0,1.0,,,,,,,
2012-01-23 09:00:00,6.5666666666666655,6.8849999999999945,0.02130000000000001,1.4343266666666665,0.02130000000000001,1.5671516666666663,1.0,2.085166666666667,1.0,1.0,,,,,,,
```

I want the output to be a csv file with header:

```
['Date','Conc','Flow','SZ','SB','RZ','RB','Fraction','Attenuation','Chanel0','Chanel1','Chanel2','Chanel3','Chanel4','Chanel5','Chanel6','Chanel7','Conc_greater_500_flag','Wind Speed','Wind Direction','Wind_direction_Flag','Wind_Speed_Less_than_4','Middle','Wind_Speed_Greater_than_10','Multiple conditions']
```

And so obviously: the contributing part from the second two files will have blanks (or better Nan's/0's for the flow, sz columns etc. And the first file will have them at the channel0-7 columns

Note the Date is the index col.

I tried `df_merged=pd.concat(df1,df2,df3)` but that seems to overlap the headers.

Also tried:

df_merged=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)

But that turns the cs output: 
into

```
,Conc,Flow,SZ,SB,RZ,RB,Fraction,Attenuation,Conc_less_-200_flag,Conc_greater_500_flag,Wind Speed,Wind Direction,Wind_direction_Flag,Wind_Speed_Less_than_4,Middle,Wind_Speed_Greater_than_10,Multiple conditions,Chanel0,Chanel1,Chanel2,Chanel3,Chanel4,Chanel5,Chanel6,Chanel7,Conc_less_-200_flag,Conc_greater_500_flag,Wind Speed,Wind Direction,Wind_direction_Flag,Wind_Speed_Less_than_4,Middle,Wind_Speed_Greater_than_10,Multiple conditions,Chanel0,Chanel1,Chanel2,Chanel3,Chanel4,Chanel5,Chanel6,Chanel7,Conc_less_-200_flag,Conc_greater_500_flag,Wind Speed,Wind Direction,Wind_direction_Flag,Wind_Speed_Less_than_4,Middle,Wind_Speed_Greater_than_10,Multiple conditions
2004-02-27 00:00:00,,,,,,,,,,,6.524999999999999,177.75,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Which is close, but it has the extra columns on the end
And I don't think overlaps the common colomns

Comment: Try `df = pd.merge(df1,df2,df3); df.to_csv('New.csv')`

Comment: df = pd.merge(df1,df2,df3)  gives:
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0):

This is idea.
First read two files into lists then set and union two list

You can checkout this answer [How to get the union of two lists using list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893916/how-to-get-the-union-of-two-lists-using-list-comprehension)

Comment: I'm using this to load them in.

df1 = pd.read_csv('Combined04.csv', index_col=0, names=names1, parse_dates=True)

What do you mean by turn the file into a list? 
That answer works great for the headers... but when tried it is lost all the data